# crystal reports filtering the group

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I created a crystal report and I have grouped my data with distinct count >1 like I have part number I filtered the parts the present more than once  and I want to filter out the groups with a specific number at the group level like if the part number is present in specific stock sat 59 show all the stock number along with 59 for that specific part number?

it's really important for me so help me if anyone know's anything

Comment: Create a parameter for part number it will display a particular part number

Comment: If you please provide more details with data?

Comment: @ArsalanKhan i have stock number and partnumber in that stock i want to show stocknumber 59 and want to show all the partnumber present in 59 and if they are present in anyother stocknumber and exclude others

Comment: @Mahendra i don't want a specific part number i want all the partnumbers that are present in 59 stocknumber and anyother

Comment: Can u provide sample data and desired  output

Comment: Yes Please provide sample data

Comment: For partnbr 11813                                                                                           stknbr    partnbr   vendornbr                                                                          59         11813       0                      68        11813          0                                   97         11813       0                      113      11813          909                               131       11813       909  @Mahendra

Comment: All i want to show is 59 for that partnbr 11813 but its vendor nbr is 0 (i want it on report) and other stcknbr with same partnbr  that has vendor 909 ans exclude all others with vendornbr 0 except 59. @ArsalanKhan

Comment: So u want stock number of those whose partner no is 11813.

Comment: Insert group for partnerno n stockno and vendorno in detail section  and then in select expert restrict vendor no =909

Answer (score 0):

Please describe your sample data properly as I understand you need to add group on stock_number and suppress group header and footer, after that by going 'Section Expert',select detail section click button against suppress then in  formula windows, write formula

```
If({stock_number}=59) then false else true;
```